# SQL for extract portion of a string

Tags: sql, oracle, delphi, interbase

I have a zipcode stored in a text field (string) and would like to select only the last 3 digits of the value in my select statement. is this possible? Is there a standard way of doing this so that the SQL is interchangeable accross databases?  I will be using it in production on Oracle, but i test on Interbase (yes, yes, i know, two totally diff DBs, but thats what i am doing)

thanks for any help you can offer

Comment: There is no substring/right command that will work `using the same  code` on both Oracle and Interbase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the zipcodes all have the same length, you can use `substr`.
If they don't have the same length, you have to do similar things with the `strlen` function.

Interbase does not have a built-in substring function, but it does have a `UDF` (user defined function) called `SUBSTR` in `lib_udf.dll` that works like this:

```
select substr(clients.lastname, 1, 10)
from clients
```

You declare the UDF like this:

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION SUBSTR
    CSTRING(80),
    SMALLINT,
    SMALLINT
RETURNS CSTRING(80) FREE_IT
ENTRY_POINT 'IB_UDF_substr' MODULE_NAME 'ib_udf';
```

Oracle does have a built-in substr function that you use like this:

```
select substr(clients.lastname, 1, 10)
from clients
```

--jeroen

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how your storing the zip code.   If you are using 5 digits only
then this should work for Oracle and may work for Interbase.

```
select * from table where substr(zip,3,3) = '014'
```

IF you store Zip + 4 and you want the last 3 digits and some are 5 digits and some are 9 digits you would have to do the following.

```
select * from table where substr(zip,length(zip) -2,3) = '014'
```

and one option that may work better in both databases is

```
select * from table where zip like '%014'
```

Comment: there is no where clause. Every record has a zip and therefore, i need the last three chars form each. And one that will work in both databases. Thanx!

Comment: to put it in the select, just move the expression substr(....) to the SELECT clause...and as noted above there is no command that will work with both Oracle and Interbase

Comment: do you have a answer for both, so i can change back and forth when need be - thankx!